# Excel - How to reference a value from another sheet with a reference from current sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

I have a document with 2 sheets: `sheet1` and `sheet2`. In `sheet1`, in column `A` I have `=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)` values. On the second column `B`, I want to reference values from column `A` from `sheet2`, however using the indices pointed out in column `A` from `sheet1`.

I tried with the following command, `=sheet2!$A$(sheet1!A1)` but with no success.
Can you please recommend me a solution to this problem?

Comment: ____________ use ***Indirect()*** _____________________

Comment: If you have 50 in Sheet1 A1 then in Sheet2 B1 `=index(A:A,sheet1!A1)` will return the contents of Sheet2 A50.

Comment: Can you please show me how to use the Indirect() function in this case scenario?

Comment: @SJR I want to display the values from `sheet2` in a column from `sheet1` using an index from `sheet1`, column `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your set up is thus (not entirely clear on this from your question):

#### On Sheet1

[image]

Formula in A1 `=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)`

Formula in B1 `=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,A1)`

#### On Sheet2

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I have another question. If instead of a value in `sheet2` I have a figure in that field. Can I display it in `sheet1`?

Comment: My pleasure. What do you mean by a figure? A shape?

Comment: It is an actual image, like an imported `png` or `jpg` file inserted in that cell.

Comment: It's possible but you would need VBA.

Comment: Ok. Please note that for some fields I have an attached images, for others I don't.