# How to display an image from another sheet with a reference from current sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel workspace with `2` sheets, in a similar manner with how they are described in this question:

[Excel - How to reference a value from another sheet with a reference from current sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579974/excel-how-to-reference-a-value-from-another-sheet-with-a-reference-from-curren)

How can I display images from `sheet2` into `sheet1` using index references from `sheet1`? One of the comments suggested VBA, however, I am new to this. Some of the cells have missing images, and in this case, I just want to skip them.

Just to be clear, `sheet2` contains a database of quiz questions, where some of the questions have a corresponding image. In `sheet1`, I want to select randomly some of the questions from `sheet2` to form up a quiz. I was able to do this with the text of the question by using the answer from the above link. However, I want to display the corresponding images from `sheet2` whenever is the case.

Below are some images with my Excel workspace.

[image][image]

I want to display the question `154` from `sheet2` onto `sheet`. I am able to do so with the answer from the above link. However, I cannot display the adjacent image to `sheet1` as in the bellow image. I tried with the command `=INDEX(sheet2!C:C,($A1 - 1)*4 + 1)`, but it failed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"display images from sheet2"*? To copy them? A screenshot would probably help to understand what you are trying. Also this *"Some of the fields have missing images."* is unclear too: What do you mean by "fields"? Cells? Be clear about the terms you use. And try to explain a bit more.

Comment: Yes, by fields I mean cells. Sorry! I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you post desired output? Its hard for me to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @simon The only way would actually be to copy the images with VBA. Therefore you need to determine the source cell (which image you want to copy) and copy paste the cell to the other sheet. Eg `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5")` The image would be pasted along with the cell. Because this is no free coding service you should give it a try on your own and come back if you have some code, get stuck or get errors.

Comment: I have not tried the solution, but a quick google of the question "How to reference picture in another cell in Excel" returned this result. Just skimming through it, it looks like a viable solution: it involves cleverly hiding words behind images and referencing the words, getting the images as a result. https://excel.tips.net/T003128_Displaying_Images_based_on_a_Result.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FormulaMacro()
'
' FormulaMacro Macro
'

'
 ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Row
 idx = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & CStr(ActiveCell.Row)).Value
 Source = "C" & CStr((idx - 1) * 4 + 1)
 Target = "C" & CStr(ActiveCell.Row)
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Source).Copy
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Target).Select
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Paste


 End Sub
```